# Search Tokens in java

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code for searching things in my project and I need to split the string into words and words into search tokens . For example If "how are you" is my string I would like to split it into how, are , you, and also h, ho, how, a, ar, are, y, yo , you.
Can anyone explain me how to do this in java?

Comment: Please show us your code. What works, what doesn't?

Comment: You can use the .contains() method in String: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: It's simply the work of **For loop** and **string tokenizer**.

Comment: Have you looked at `String.split()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.split() would be the ideal choice - it takes a regular expressions -- which can be used to define everything from the very simplest of patterns to the most complex ones .

As per Java API Doc -

StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to use is StringTokenizer. (or BreakIterator)

```
  Multiset<String> myList = new HashMultiset.create() //Multiset is part of Google Guava Library

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("How are you");
         while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        myList.add(st.nextToken());

         }


//Now check if multiset already contains it : 

if(myList.contains("how"){
//do whatever you want.
}
```

Comment: List<String> searchableContent = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] questionTokens = question.getValue().split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < questionTokens.length; i++)
{
for (int j = 1; j <= questionTokens[i].length(); j++)
{
if (!searchableContent.contains(questionTokens[i].substring(0,j))) 
{

searchableContent.add(questionTokens[i].substring(0,j).toLowerCase();
}
}
}
This helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Use StringTokenizer to split into tokens and then read them into a variable/array/list and use them as you wish.